# Command line: View network duration

Tags: windows, networking, command-line-interface

I can see network duration in lan status snippet. How can I see it in command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time of last interface reset, which is the base for duration calculation:

```
wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed, TimeOfLastReset
```

Comment: Nice.  'wmic NIC  get Name, Speed, TimeOfLastReset' works for my XP